# How can I alias a command with arguments?

Tags: command

All I want to do is to change `:vertical resize` + arguments into `:vr` + arguments.

for example change:

```
:vertical resize +60 <CR>
```

into:

```
:vr +60 <CR>
```

From other answers [Aliasing a command in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3878710/5402169), I can see that i can use `:command`, but there doesn't seem to be a simple way to pass arguments in the process of aliasing.

also as a sidenote, I have tried the following and it doesn't seem to pass in the argument:

```
command! -nargs=1 Vres "vertical resize"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> it doesn't seem to pass in the argument

Because you haven't passed it. The right syntax is:

```
command! -nargs=1 Vres vertical resize <args>
```

Simply read `:help :command` until the very end to know all the options.